# nodejs get error 'originalType.toConfig is not a function'

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql

I am trying to make a test run of an application using graphql. But I get the error

**types resolvers**
`src/api/Hello/sayBye/sayBye.graphql`

```
type Query {
    sayBye: String!
}
```

`src/api/Hello/sayBye/sayBye.resolvers.ts`

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        sayBye: () => "Hello from sayBye"
    }
}

export default resolvers;
```

`src/api/Hello/sayHello/sayHello.graphql`

```
type Query {
    sayHello: String!
}
```

`src/api/Hello/sayHello/sayHello.resolvers.ts`

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        sayHello: () => "Hello from sayHello"
    }
}

export default resolvers;
```

**merge types and resolvers**
src/schema.ts

```
import { GraphQLSchema } from "graphql";
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';
import { fileLoader, mergeTypes, mergeResolvers } from "merge-graphql-schemas";
import * as path from "path";

const allTypes: GraphQLSchema[] = fileLoader(
    path.join(__dirname, "./api/**/*.graphql")
);

const allResolvers = fileLoader(
    path.join(__dirname, "./api/**/*.resolvers.*")
);

const mergedTypes = mergeTypes(allTypes);
const mergedResolvers = mergeResolvers(allResolvers);

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs: mergedTypes,
    resolvers: mergedResolvers
});

export default schema;
```

**error**

> [nodemon] starting `ts-node index.ts`
>
> /var/www/html/dist/utils/src/mapSchema.js:205
> Object.keys(originalTypeMap).forEach(typeName => { ^ TypeError:
> originalType.toConfig is not a function at
> /var/www/html/dist/utils/src/mapSchema.js:217:41 at Array.forEach
> () at mapArguments
> (/var/www/html/dist/utils/src/mapSchema.js:205:34) at mapDefaultValues
> (/var/www/html/dist/utils/src/mapSchema.js:97:24) at Object.mapSchema
> (/var/www/html/dist/utils/src/mapSchema.js:7:22) at
> createNewSchemaWithResolvers
> (/var/www/html/dist/schema/src/addResolversToSchema.js:200:14) at
> addResolversToSchema
> (/var/www/html/dist/schema/src/addResolversToSchema.js:87:11) at
> schemaTransforms
> (/var/www/html/dist/schema/src/makeExecutableSchema.js:66:41) at
> /var/www/html/dist/schema/src/makeExecutableSchema.js:108:65 at
> Array.reduce () [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file
> changes before starting...

Comment: What version of `graphql` are you using?

Comment: @DanielRearden im use "graphql-yoga": "^1.18.3", - yoga use "graphql": "^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0",
In node_modules package graphql. In him package.jsom declared "version": "0.13.2"

Comment: @DanielRearden I have double-checked the package versions and everything works, thanks